# @Inject CDI not working with JAX-RS

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, cdi

I'm trying to create a simple REST service with JAX-RS (Jersey), without using Spring. I want to have the typical structure of: Resource, that use a Service (typical interface with method `findById`, findAll...), and that Service injected in the Resource.

It seems that CDI automatically scans beans and injects them (having a empty `beans.xml` in the project) but... it doesn't work for me.

This is my Resource class:

```
@Path("users")
@ManagedBean
public class UserController {

    @Inject
    private UserService userService;

    @GET()
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public User getUserById(@PathParam("id") Long id) {

        return userService.findById(id);
    }
}
```

And this is my Service and its impl class (it´s a mock...):

```
public interface UserService {

    User findById(Long id);

    List<User> findAll();

    User save(User user);

    User update(User user);

    void delete(Long id);
}

public class UserServiceMock implements UserService {

    // omitted constants

    @Override
    public User findById(Long id) {
        return new User()
                .setId(id)
                .setName(NAME_GANDALF)
                .setPhone(PHONE_666554433)
                .setType(TYPE_1)
                .setBirthDate(LocalDate.parse(STRING_DATE_19110102));
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                new User()
                        .setId(USER_ID_12)
                        .setName(NAME_GANDALF)
                        .setPhone(PHONE_666554433)
                        .setType(TYPE_1)
                        .setBirthDate(LocalDate.parse(STRING_DATE_19110102)),
                new User()
                        .setId(USER_ID_140)
                        .setName(NAME_ARAGORN)
                        .setPhone(PHONE_661534411)
                        .setType(TYPE_1)
                        .setBirthDate(LocalDate.parse(STRING_DATE_19230716)),
                new User()
                        .setId(USER_ID_453321)
                        .setName(NAME_FRODO)
                        .setPhone(PHONE_666222211)
                        .setType(TYPE_2)
                        .setBirthDate(LocalDate.parse(STRING_DATE_19511124))
        );
    }

    @Override
    public User save(User user) {
        return user.setId(USER_ID_453321);
    }

    @Override
    public User update(User user) {
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Long id) {
        // delete user by id
    }
}
```

And I'm using a "no web.xml" configuration, with this class:

```
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class RestApplication extends ResourceConfig {

}
```

The only workaround I found is to "register" the service in the RestApplication class:

```
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class RestApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public RestApplication() {
        register(UserController.class);

        register(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(new UserServiceMock()).to(UserService.class);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Is there another solution to this problem? I'd rather not to register all my services and other stuff in this class manually...
I tried with annotations like `@Default`, `@Qualifier` and more (in the service), and no one works...

Comment: Are you running it in Java EE 7 or Java EE 6 compliant container (and respective JDK)?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. I'm using Tomcat 8, and java 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tomcat is a **servlet** container only. It's not a full Java EE enterprise stack, nor does it contain a CDI container. [Apache TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html), on the other hand, is Tomcat with EE capabilities.

Bauke Scholtz, the infamous BalusC, wrote an excellent blog on [installing CDI on Tomcat](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-install-cdi-in-tomcat.html). This might help you. Otherwise, an alternative approach will be to install [Apache TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html) and run your application from there. After all, it's still Tomcat anyway.

Comment: Or ditch Tomcat and use [GlassFish](https://glassfish.java.net/) instead, which is what I did.

Comment: Thank you very much! I always use tomcat for all and I forgot that... I've just tried with glassfish and it works! :)

Comment: It works with Tomcat too; its not JEE specific, you just need a proper Servlet 3.0 compatible container to be able to deploy without having any web.xml configuration. "Works on my machine", I wouldn't say that completely switching out the server software because you can't figure it out is a proper answer to this question. Possibly the implementation of JAX-RS you were using is simply too old.

Comment: @Gimby Servlet 3 technology won't help since the CDI Container is not a Servlet container at all. Thus, the only way Tomcat will do CDI injection is through retrieving `BeanManager` from JNDI lookup. Hence I said, to rather use a Java EE complaint container, preferably the container that has a CDI container (thus alleviating JNDI lookups).